# hooking up button in JS without using the onclick event

Tags: javascript, button, events

```
<button id=trainingbutton document.getElementById("trainingbutton").addEventListener("click", 
  }); ></button>

function(){
    trainingbuttonclicked=()=>document.getElementById("trainingbtn").innerHTML = "Hello World";
```

Completely new to JavaScript and am trying to hook up a button to show an alert. Above is my HTML first and my app.js is below. I would like to try to hook up the event without using a simple onclick event handler. My preferred method would be either the event handler or the inner HTML method. Any advice appreciated. I know it's something simple but maybe Ive been staring at it too long, because I can't see the answer

Comment: You don't call `addEventListener` inside HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need your script tag in order to insert an eventlistener, like so

```
<script>
  const button = document.querySelector('#trainingButton"); // # id's and . for selecting a 
  class in the dom (document object model)

  button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const string = 'some string';
    alert(string);
  });
</script>


Your Button id should only contain a string like trainingButton so that it becomes <button id="trainingButton">



> the script tag should be placed in the bottom of your body tag, in order for the DOM to load properly before any javascript runs

for more info

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your HTML from your javascript. You can either have them in separate files or in the same.

If you'd like them in the same file you can do the following. (Note: the script has to be after the button because we want it to run after the button has been created)

```html
<button id="trainingbutton">Training Button</button>

<script>
  var trainingbutton = document.getElementById("trainingbutton");
  trainingbutton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    trainingbutton.innerHTML = "Hello World";
  });
</script>
```

You can also define the script above between the script tags in a seperate file (*.js) and link it to your HTML file using `<script src='*.js'></script>`. As you add more to your HTML and JS it can help to organize.